# Using SASS in JSF Web Application

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, sass

I am starting to learn JSF/PrimeFacess.

I am playing around and trying to figure out the best way to use **sass** instead of writing pure css for the project.

I have looked at gulp and the possibilities to automate workflows such as compiling **sass** files to **css**

Now my question is where the best place to put the **sass** files in the jsf/primeface project directory tree?

My though is to create a sub-folder in `src` named `sass` and use gulp.js to watch the folder and compile all changes to the sass files an puth them in the `resources/css` folder in `web/WEB-INF/css.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Quite so, the usual file structure for javascript client-side apps is to have a 'source' and a 'dest'. The source is usually called 'client', or 'src' with the css in a 'client/css' or 'src/sass' folder.
The output is usually in a 'public', 'dest', 'assets' or 'build' folder with the css/sass folder respectively inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than keeping the folder structure resources/css, it will be better if the folder structure would be something like **includes/public/resources/common/css**, or something module specific, or generic like **includes/public/resources/MODULE_NAME/css** to align in a better project structure.

Hope this helps!